# Como fazer uma requisição POST em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

Gostaria de saber como faço uma requisição `POST` [nesta URL](http://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/arquivos/orgao_oficial/seleciona_ano_oom.php), para depois chegar chegar [nessa página](http://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/arquivos/orgao_oficial/paginar_orgao_oficial_ano.php).

Onde tenho que passar o ano na *div* do orgão fiscal sem assinatura.

Comment: Você quer escrever um robô que manipule esta página, é isso?

Comment: Isso, estou fazendo um robo que baixe os pdfs dela.

Comment: Você já tem algum código começado?

Answer (score 6):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso o que você quer, as mais comuns são com o uso das funções do módulo [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) (em Python 3 é [`http.client`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)) ou [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

A [página](http://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/arquivos/orgao_oficial/seleciona_ano_oom.php) que você quer fazer a requisição, aparentemente recebe dois parâmetros, `ano` e `entrar`. Uma maneira de fazer isto com o módulo `urllib` é:

```
def funcao(url, ano):
    parametros = urllib.urlencode({'ano': ano, 'entrar': 'Buscar'})
    html = urllib.urlopen(url, parametros).read()
    return html
```

Para obter o resultado faça o seguinte:

```
url  = "http://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/arquivos/orgao_oficial/paginar_orgao_oficial_ano.php"
ano  = 2015
html = funcao(url, ano)
print (html)
```

Para extrair as informações desse HTML você pode usar expressões regulares ou um analisador (*parser*), para esta última, pode ser usado o módulo [**Beautiful Soup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), exemplo:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# Extrai todos os links do elemento a
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Exemplo completo:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup # Ou: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def funcao(url, ano):
    parametros = urllib.urlencode({'ano': ano, 'entrar': 'Buscar'})
    html = urllib.urlopen(url, parametros).read()
    return html

url  = "http://venus.maringa.pr.gov.br/arquivos/orgao_oficial/paginar_orgao_oficial_ano.php"
ano  = 2015
html = funcao(url, ano)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

- [**Instruções para baixar e instalar o Beautiful Soup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download)
- [**Documentação**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)