# Como abrir um conteúdo remoto com python?

Tags: python

No PHP, quando quero obter um conteúdo remoto (alguma url, por exemplo), utilizo as funções próprias para abrir arquivos e isso funciona perfeitamente.

Exemplo:

```
file_get_contents('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
```

E em Python, qual é a forma correta para abrir um conteúdo remoto?

Comment: Não existe forma correta, o que existe é biblioteca adequada a versão especifica do Python, isto deve lhe ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56617/3635

Comment: Com certeza, ajuda. Se quiser marcar a pergunta...

Comment: Eu acho que pode variar as versões do python, vou ver ao certo. Acho que falta ainda alguns detalhes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2

def file_get_contents(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: Não vou declarar a função com esse nome, mas a solução foi bacana :)

Answer (score 0):

Essa resposta vai depender da versão do Python. A resposta do @sergiopereira funciona perfeitamente para o Python 2. Mas no Python 3, por exemplo, não encontrei a `urllib2`, e sim `urllib3`, que é um pouco diferente o uso.

Veja:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/')

if response.status == 200:
    print(response.data) # resultado da página é exibido aqui
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem proxy:

```
import requests

requests.get('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
```

Com proxy:

```
import requests

requests.get('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/', 
proxies={'http':'http://10.1.1.1:8080', 'https': 'https://10.1.1.1:8080'})
```

ou

```
import requests
proxies_cfg={
    'http':'http://10.1.1.1:8080', 
    'https': 'https://10.1.1.1:8080',
    'ftp':'http://10.1.1.1:8061',
}
import requests
requests.get('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/', proxies=proxies_cfg)
```