# Python Requisição Básica

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso fazer uma requisição básica em Python para um WebServer ?

Estou tentando, porém sem sucesso.

Desejo em `get`, da maneira mais simples mesmo.

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Como fazer uma requisição POST em Python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56617/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-post-em-python)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Como abrir um conteúdo remoto com python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80598/como-abrir-um-conte%C3%BAdo-remoto-com-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar a lib [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Importe através do pip:

```
$ pip install requests
```

Exemplo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Comment: quando tento importar da erro ... Uso mac

Comment: instala através do pip: $ pip install requests

Comment: instalei, ja reconheceu, porem fiz um request localhost e pedi o print r.text que seria para mostrar os arquivos do meu server, porem sem sucesso....

Comment: agora deu certo, n tinha colocado o http nem a porta... Obg

Comment: ah sim, pode crer, que bom que funcionou :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import httplib, urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
>>> headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
...            "Accept": "text/plain"}
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
>>> conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
>>> response = conn.getresponse()
>>> print response.status, response.reason
302 Found
>>> data = response.read()
>>> data
'Redirecting to <a href="http://bugs.python.org/issue12524">http://bugs.python.org/issue12524</a>'
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: não reconhece as libs

Comment: É interessante enfatizar que esta é a forma de fazer o request sem precisar instalar nad aalém do que vem com o Python. Na "vida real"  sempre utilizamos o módulo "requests"  instalado à parte, por que ele realmente simplifica muito as coisas. Sò não está na biblioteca padrão para não ficar preso ao release cycle do Python para versões mais novas.

Comment: Ademais - o exemplo é feito em Python 2 - o módulo `httplib` foi alterado nas versões 3 do Python para `http.client`